# Get rid of Option [T] when get values from Map[T, T]

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am writing my own Semigroup for Map [T, T]. The logic of the function is as follows:

in case of the same key the values should be combined in the result map.

in case of different keys the values should be added to the result map.

I wrote this function, but I ran into a problem: the `get(key)` method returns not just `T`, but `Option[T]`.

What are the ways to solve this problem?

```
  trait Semigroup[T]:
    extension (left: T) def combine(right: T): T

  given Semigroup[Int] with
    extension (left: Int) def combine(right: Int): Int = ???

  given Semigroup[String] with
    extension (left: String) def combine(right: String): String = ???

  given [T]: Semigroup[List[T]] with
    extension (left: List[T]) def combine(right: List[T]): List[T] = ???
  
  given [T: Semigroup]: Semigroup[Map[String, T]] with
    extension (left: Map[String, T])
      def combine(right: Map[String, T]): Map[String, T] = {
        (left.keySet ++ right.keySet) map { key => key -> (summon[Semigroup[T]].combine(left.get(key)) { right.get(key)} ) } toMap
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to remove the **Option**, it is what will tell you if you need to `combine` the values because the key is present in both **Maps**; or otherwise, just preserve the value.

```scala
(left.keySet | right.keySet).iterator.map { key =>
  val value = (left.get(key), right.get(key)) match  {
    case (Some(v1), Some(v2)) => v1.combine(v2)
    case (None, Some(v)) => v
    case (Some(v), None) => v
    case (None, None) => ??? // Should never happend.
  }
  key -> value
}.toMap
```

---

*See the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/VNK8mZKVR7G5uyNPqqzbvQ/12)*.

Comment: @ElenaVisnya oh okay, sorry for the confusion. I fixed the answer, you may also take a look at Dima's one. - BTW, it would be good to delete the old comments.

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is a *good* thing :) It protects you from crashing when key is not in a map.

```
  (left.keySet ++ right.keySet) 
     .map { key => key -> (left.get(key), right.get(key)) }
     .flatMap { case (k, (l, r) => 
        l.zip(r)
          .map { case (x,y) => summon[Semigroup[T]].combine(x)(y)))
          .orElse(l)
          .orElse(r)
          .map(key -> _)
     }.toMap
```

Or, maybe make a special semigroup for options (I am not sure about scala3 syntax, but something like this I think):

```
 given [T : Semigroup]: Semigroup[Option[T]] with
    extension (left: Option[T]) def combine(right: Option[T]): Option[T] =
        left.zip(right).map { case(l,r) => summon[Semigroup[T]].combine(l)(r) }
           .orElse(l)
           .orElse(r)
```

Then you can just write

```
    (left.keySet ++ right.keySet).map { key =>
       key -> summon[Semigroup[Option[T]].combine(left.get(key))(right.get(key))
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just thought about a better option :) You should not have to deal with merging map keys explicitly ...

```
    (left.toSeq ++ right.toSeq)
      .groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(summon[Semigroup[T]].combine(_)(_))
```

`groupMapReduce` fееls a little like black magic, but it's basically a combination of `groupBy(_.Ь1)`, `mapValues(_.map(_._2))` (dropping the key from grouped lists), and `reduce(combine)` (combining the grouped values in the the list.